# Eloquent with(), select() and where() selection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is my query to fetch data from 2 different table.

```
$variant = Variant::with(['v_detail' => function($q){
            $q->select('variant_dtl_name');
        }])->where('product_id','=',$productId)->get();
```

There is output, but `v_detail` returning empty list

result:

```
created_at: "2015-11-07 12:37:26"
id: 1
product_id: 30
updated_at: "2015-11-07 12:37:26"
v_detail: []
variant_name: "Pricing"
```

But with these query:

```
$variant = Variant::with('v_detail')->where('product_id','=',$productId)->get();
```

The result is:

```
created_at: "2015-11-07 12:37:26"
id: 1
product_id: 30
updated_at: "2015-11-07 12:37:26"
v_detail: [{id: 1, variant_id: 1, variant_dtl_name: "Adult", variant_dtl_price: 25,…},…]
0: {id: 1, variant_id: 1, variant_dtl_name: "Adult", variant_dtl_price: 25,…}
1: {id: 2, variant_id: 1, variant_dtl_name: "Senior", variant_dtl_price: 15,…}
2: {id: 3, variant_id: 1, variant_dtl_name: "Children", variant_dtl_price: 8,…}
variant_name: "Pricing"
```

Now, on the query that work, how can I fetch a specific column names. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```php
$variant = Variant::with(['v_detail' => function($q)
{
    // Either add the related foreign key or select all
    $q->select('related_foreign_key', 'variant_dtl_name');

}])->where('product_id','=',$productId)->get();
```

Since you are selecting only a single field which is `variant_dtl_name` then it's not possible to find out the related models because the relation builder foreign key is required. So, you have to select that foreign key as well. Notice the `related_foreign_key` in sub-query so use the right one, probably that is `variant_id` but not sure because you didn't mention anything about that.